# Null pointer Exception in Parcelable android

Tags: android, parcelable

i want to send list of array objects from activity to fragments so that i create parcelable class, data's being passed and everything works fine, but when ever i pressed home button it throws NPE in writeToParcel method. Please provide me some suggestion

Here is my parcelable class

```
public class SimilarAppsParcel implements Parcelable {

List<SimilarAppsBean> similarAppsBeanList = null;
SimilarAppsBean similarAppsBean = null;

public SimilarAppsParcel(List<SimilarAppsBean> similarAppsBeanList) {
    super();
    this.similarAppsBeanList = similarAppsBeanList;
}

public List<SimilarAppsBean> getParcelList() {
    return similarAppsBeanList;
}

private SimilarAppsParcel(Parcel in) {

    similarAppsBean = new SimilarAppsBean();

    similarAppsBean.setRating(in.readFloat());
    similarAppsBean.setPrice(in.readString());
    similarAppsBean.setTitle(in.readString());

    similarAppsBeanList.add(similarAppsBean);

}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int flags) {

    parcel.writeFloat(similarAppsBean.getRating());
    parcel.writeString(similarAppsBean.getPrice());
    parcel.writeString(similarAppsBean.getTitle());

    similarAppsBeanList.add(similarAppsBean);
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<SimilarAppsParcel> CREATOR =
        new Parcelable.Creator<SimilarAppsParcel>() {
            public SimilarAppsParcel createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
                return new SimilarAppsParcel(in);
            }

            public SimilarAppsParcel[] newArray(int size) {
                return new SimilarAppsParcel[size];
            }
        };
```

}

Here is the code how i make parcel in activity,

```
  private void makeSimilarAppsTabParcel(List<SimilarAppsBean> list) {

    // send the list of SimilarAppsBean to SimilarAppsParcel class to create the parcel
    SimilarAppsParcel similarAppsParcel=new SimilarAppsParcel(list);
    bundle_SimilarApps=new Bundle();
    bundle_SimilarApps.putParcelable("SimilarApps",similarAppsParcel);
}
```

Here is the code how i receive parcel in frarment,

```
   Bundle bundle=this.getArguments();
   SimilarAppsParcel similarAppsParcel=bundle.getParcelable("SimilarApps");
   List<SimilarAppsBean> list=similarAppsParcel.getParcelList();
```

Here is my Logcat,

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException
        at appstore.com.parcelable.SimilarAppsParcel.writeToParcel(SimilarAppsParcel.java:50)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1254)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1173)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:591)
        at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1619)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:605)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentState.writeToParcel(Fragment.java:136)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeTypedArray(Parcel.java:1102)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerState.writeToParcel(FragmentManager.java:381)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1254)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1173)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:591)
        at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1619)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:605)
        at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.activityStopped(ActivityManagerNative.java:2269)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:3214)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5297)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: indicate `SimilarAppsParcel.java:50`

Comment: parcel.writeFloat(similarAppsBean.getRating());

Comment: `similarAppsBean` is null in your code, or `similarAppsBean.getRating()` is null , check those

Comment: `similarAppsBean` is just instantiated in this constructor `SimilarAppsParcel(Parcel in)`, I think it has to be instantiated also in `SimilarAppsParcel(List<SimilarAppsBean> similarAppsBeanList)` because that's the constructor you are using in `makeSimilarAppsTabParcel`.

Comment: SimilarAppsParcel(Parcel in) this constructor is private.